# Square Cash Tender Process

Tags: square-connect, pos

Using the new Square API V2, are we able now to add a cash tender button on the Square register using their marketplace?

We would like to add an optional cash tender button to the existing Square cash tender process to allow an API call to our servers and interact with our servers to print something on the receipt- something that is unique to each transaction.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently not possible.

Comment: It looks like the APIs are designed for creating a custom POS rather than interacting with the Square register app.  Is this correct?  Or am I able to view transaction details from the register thru APIs?

Comment: Correct. Our current APIs are focused around creating either your own web application for taking payments online, or your own mobile application for taking in-person payments.You can also do other things like create customers, items, etc, but those are the main two "buckets".